# Real REST-API format for GET /users/:id

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Current code:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity get(@RequestParam(value="id", defaultValue="") String id) {}
```

This will work for URLs like `/user` to return all users and `/user?id=123` to return a specific user.

Is there a way to achieve real REST URLs so that `/user/123` will return the user with the ID 123?

Comment: Use `@RequestMapping(path = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)` and `get(@PathVariable String id)`.

Comment: Also read here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates

Comment: Works like a charme, thank you!